# Не могу загрузить много фоток в 1 колонку PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, postgresql

У меня есть интернет магазин я его создаю и мне нужно к каждому ноутбуку добавить к примеру по 6 фотографий как мне лучше хранить эти фотографии , если постгре не поддерживает обьекты, массивы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых, постгре поддерживает массивы. Во-вторых, используйте связь один-ко-многим - для хранения фото создайте вторую таблицу. В-третьих, при чём тут javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Фотографии лучше не хранить в БД. Рекомендую Вам хранить фотографии в папке на диске, а в БД сохранять пути (URL) к ним.

Comment: В этом случае сложно поддерживать транзакционную целостность.